# Embedding matplotlib in python tkinter (runtime error)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to embed a matplotlib bar chart to python tkinter. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from Tkinter import*
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def trend_quit():
   trend_root.quit()
   trend_root.destroy()
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(211)

systems=['system a','system b','system c','system d','system e']
N=len(systems)
ind=np.arange(N)
width=0.25
list_a=(1,3,4,3,6)
x=np.arange(0,5,1)
ax.set_xlabel('System')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of faults')
ax.set_ylim(0, 6)
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels(systems,rotation='vertical')
rects1=ax.bar(ind+0.11,list_a,width,color='b')
rects2=ax.plot(x,list_a,color='r')
ax.grid(True)

trend_root=Tk()
trend_root.overrideredirect(True)
trend_root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1200, 600, 50, 100))
trend_root.config(bg='white',relief=SOLID,bd=1)

trend_frame1=Frame(trend_root,bg='black',width=1200,relief=GROOVE,height=50)
trend_frame1.place(x=0,y=0)

trend_frame2=Frame(trend_root,bg='black',width=1000,relief=GROOVE,height=700)
trend_frame2.place(x=20,y=60)

trend_label1=Label(trend_frame1,text="Trends",font=('calibri',(18)),bg='black',fg='white')
trend_label1.place(x=10,y=5)

trend_button1=Button(trend_frame1,text='EXIT',font=('calibri',(12)),bg='red',command=trend_quit)
trend_button1.place(x=1100,y=10)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=trend_frame2)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,trend_frame2 )
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def on_key_event(event):
    print('you pressed %s'%event.key)
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key_event)
trend_root.mainloop()
```

everything works fine! but when i quit the program using the Exit button that i added on top, it gave me error message saying that "C++ run time error"- this app has requested the c++ run time to terminate in unusual way. What did i do wrong?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem, your code works fine for me. However, I've found [this bug](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2007-August/039262.html) which _might_ be related. A shot in the dark: Are you running this from the IDLE?

Comment: I am not using IDLE but just out of curiosity.. can't it be run from IDLE? anyway, the link you provided give me some clue.. i am using pythonwin at the moment.. so i will try again with other IDE. thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Sometimes I have this error, too. Could it be that it appperars only witth threads? Do you open threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to solve the problem. I don't know the exact cause of the problem but after i uninstalled my pythonwin , it seems to work fine without giving me anymore error messages. Thanks A.Rodas for your link for pointing out about pythonwin.